# How does CosmosDB scale graphs?

Tags: azure, graph, nosql, scalability, azure-cosmosdb

I'm just getting started with graph databases and Azure CosmosDB. As defined by Microsoft:

> Azure Cosmos DB is a fully managed graph database that offers global
>   distribution, elastic scaling of storage and throughput, automatic
>   indexing and query, tunable consistency levels, and support for the
>   TinkerPop standard.

My question here is how does Cosmos DB achieve global distribution and scaling of graphs? Is a graph replicated **fully** (like master-slave setup) on multiple machines or is it cut in meaningful pieces and **sharded** across machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph will be sharded across multiple machines
( physical partitions). As the size of the graphs grow the partitions will split automatically.

How the graph will be sharded would be based on user input ( aka partition key). During the creation of graph, one can pick a vertex property to be the partition key, and the graph nodes will be distributed based on that.

Comment: Thanks. Since CosmosDB seems to have only one write region, does that mean all physical write partitions will be in that region?